# Adodb Recordset function .MoveNext Causes Exception "UPDATE permission was denied"

Tags: vb.net, adodb, recordset

I've run into a problem today that has stumped me.

Here is some sample code:

```
                Dim objRec As ADODB.Recordset 
                Dim oRec As ADODB.Recordset 
                Dim oRecBuild As New ADODB.Recordset 
                cmd = New ADODB.Command()
                cmd.ActiveConnection = objConn
                cmd.CommandText = "SelectAll_PhoneNumbers_ById"
                cmd.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc
                cmd.NamedParameters = True

                cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@ObjId", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 20, objRec.Fields("PK_ProgramID").Value))

                oRec = New ADODB.Recordset()
                oRec.Open(cmd, , ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)

                If oRec.EOF = False Then
                    Do Until oRec.EOF
                        If IsDBNull(oRec.Fields("PhoneType").Value) = False Then
                            sName = PhoneNumberEdit(oRec.Fields("Phone").Value)
                            If IsDBNull(oRec.Fields("Extension").Value) = False And Len(oRec.Fields("Extension").Value) > 0 Then
                                sName = PhoneNumberEdit(oRec.Fields("Phone").Value) & " " & oRec.Fields("Extension").Value
                            End If
                            oRecBuild.AddNew(New Object() {"TextPrint", "TextType"}, New Object() {sName, oRec.Fields("PhoneType")})
                        End If
                        oRec.MoveNext()
                    Loop
                End If
```

When I reach the .MoveNext() function the app throws an error that reads like this: The UPDATE permission was denied on the object 'PhoneNumbers', database 'MyDb', schema 'dbo'.

Nothing in this code block is calling an update (the function calls in the loop are just formatting data), does anyone have any idea of what could be causing this?

I should also add that I can run this using SSPI locally, however the code needs to be able to run on a server using a SQL username and PW; I have tested updates with the app on other pages, and it works fine.

Comment: old recordset code in .Net makes me sad :( ADO.Net is 13 years old now. It's time to stop writing db code like it's still the 90's.

Comment: It's an upgrade, we don't have time to rewrite everything. If I had the choice it wouldn't be this way.

Comment: If possible, run Sql Profiler on the database (assuming MS Sql), so you can see the exact query being sent to the DB.  This might give you a clue about what is causing the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question, I wanted to go ahead and say that I finally was able to get this resolved. The issue was that dynamic sql being executed with sp_executesql explicitly checks the select, insert, or update privileges of the SQL user; execute privs are NOT enough.

So, either the dynamic SQL has to be done away with or the select/update/insert/delete privs must be granted.

Thank you all for the help and time.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hunch, but I do see one place in that code that *might* result in an UPDATE commend: `oRecBuild.AddNew()`. I don't see how it could, but I wonder if calling `oRec.MoveNext()` is somehow forcing a commit from `oRecBuild`. Otherwise, I'd take a longer look at the `SelectAll_PhoneNumbers_ById` procedure, and any possible triggers that might be attached to tables or views it uses.

And if that fails, I'd do this:

```
Public Class PhoneNumber
    Public Number As String
    Public PhoneType As String
End Public
'...

Dim result As New List(Of PhoneNumber)
Using cn As New SqlConnection("connection string"), _
      cmd As New SqlCommand("SelectAll_PhoneNumbers_ById", cn)

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    'Is this really an integer?
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ObjId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = objRec.Fields("PK_ProgramID").Value
    cn.Open()

    Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
       While rdr.Read()
          Dim phone As String = ""
          If Not IsDbNull(rdr("PhoneType"))
              phone = PhoneNumberEdit(rdr("Phone"))
          End If
          If Not IsDbNull(rdr("Extension"))
              phone = phone & " " & PhoneNumberEdit(rdr("Extension"))
          End If
          result.Add(New PhoneNumber With {.Number = phone, .PhoneType = rdr("PhoneType")})
       End While
    End Using      
End Using
```

While I'm at it... anytime you're reading data from one recordset into another there's a very strong chance that the whole thing could be done entirely in the database, with no client code at all.